# ATI legacy drivers for 14.10

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx

Graphic card: ATI Radeon HD4890 (1 GB)
The issue is that I have Ubuntu 14.10 (Gnome if this is of any relevance at all) and the fglrx driver doesn't work. It worked on 14.04, so what to do?
1) Maybe some way to install it from a 14.04 repo? Will it be compatible? Is there any separate driver for 14.04 and 14.10?
2) Wait for it to be implemented? (Will it? It's quite an old card...)
3) Any substitute?
I installed it after a bit of a struggle, but of course x.org doesn't start after reboot correctly. Simply purging the package fixes the issue, fortunately.

Comment: no way - i have the same card and are back on windows
u have to downgrade the x-server to run the driver - this mean u have to downgrade a lot of packages -> u will be back in 12.04 after that